# Anylogic: truncated class error during optimization

Tags: optimization, anylogic, truncated

I state that I am a beginner, here is my problem.
My model works perfectly when I run it with a normal simulation. Now I'm trying to optimize some parameters using the optimization experiment, I've followed all the steps of the [official tutorial](https://www.anylogic.com/resources/educational-videos/how-to-video-optimization-experiment-/), but it doesn't work because I get "Exception during discrete event execution:
Truncated class file". The strange thing is that, looking into the console displaying the error, I see that some lines are referred to an old version of my model, for example:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
    at coffe_maker.Main._m1_1_delayTime_xjal(Main.java:14070)
```

The current model's name is coffee_maker_v2_6 so I don't understand why I get this kind of error, do you know if it is normal? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved: the problem was that, in every delay block of my model, the delay time was linked with a database reference (type code), now I am trying by tyiping the probability distributions in the delays directly and now the optimization works

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that you have Java code left in an 'unused' configuration of a Delay block's "Delay time" expression (e.g., it *now* has a static value but you had  Java code in the now-switched-out dynamic value).

Unfortunately, AnyLogic sometimes still includes the switched-out code in the compiled class, and this can sometimes cause strange runtime errors such as that one.

If this does look to be the case, temporarily switch to the offending switched-out configuration and delete it before switching back to the correct one.